# X and Y have same distribution. Is the distribution of X-Y symmetric to 0?

Tags: probability, statistics

I met this question when I went through non parameter test. I know X-Y may not be 0. Like X follows standard normal. So does -X. But X-(-X)=2X. I just wonder is X-Y (the pdf, if exists) symmetric to 0.  Without the condition of independence. I cannot prove it. Nor can 
I find some counter example. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X,Y)$ be $(3,2)$, $(2,1)$ or $(1,3)$ with with each pair having probability $\frac13$.

$X$ and $Y$ each have the same distribution since each can be $1$, $2$ or $3$ with equal probabilities.

You can see that $X-Y=1$ with probability $\frac23$ and $X-Y=-2$ with probability $\frac13$.

This is not a symmetric distribution.